# Angular service injection error for no provider

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-module

I have an angular app (v10.1) that is using routing.

In short, I am using modules to take advantage of lazy loading
the basic dir structure looks like this

```
ROOT
    /modules
        /myMod
            myMod.component.ts
```

the myMod component needs to make use of some services, and so I am trying to include the service (location.service) and declare it in the constructor.

I get an error

```
core.js:4352 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): 
    NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(myModModule)[LocationService -> LocationService -> LocationService -> LocationService -> LocationService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for LocationService!
```

I have tried to add this service to a provider array in @NgModule
BUT I have 3 modules to consider ROOT,Resource,myMod

I have tried adding the service to each of these respectively, to no avail - still get the error

Here is a little bit more detailed diagram of the app
Please dont tell me I need to add the service to each of the mods, and if Im missusing modules can someone please explain. Thx

```
ROOT
-app.module
-app-routing.module
-app.component.html (has link routerLink="/resources/myMod" )

-- modules/resources
----resources-routing.module.ts
        const routes: Routes = [{
                path: 'myMod', loadChildren: () => import('../myMod/myMod.module').then((m) => m.myModModule),
            }]

-- modules/myMod
----myMod.module.ts
        import { myModRoutingModule } from './myMod-routing.module';
        import { myModComponent } from './myMod.component';
        @NgModule({
            declarations: [myModComponent],
            imports: [CommonModule, myModRoutingModule]
        })
        export class myModModule {}

----myMod.component.ts
        import { LocationService } from '../../common/services/location.service';
        @Component({
            selector: 'app-myMod',
            templateUrl: './myMod.component.html'
        })
        export class myModComponent implements OnInit {
            constructor( private locationService: LocationService )
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-injection-error1

[image]

Comment: Please include the service class as well, and what version of Angular you're building in. The most likely culprit is that your `@Injectable` annotation is either missing or is missing the `providedIn` property.

Comment: @El-Mo - v10.1 - service above

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your [@Injectable](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#injectable) annotation is missing the `providedIn` property.

Adding it should resolve the issue:

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class LocationService {
  ...
}
```

Comment: El-mo - that worked - until I added 
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
now that doesnt even work

Comment: Is there an error on the console associated with the imports?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): 
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CollegesModule)[CollegeService -> CollegeService -> CollegeService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
- this is a college service, loaded right after the location service, that uses httpClient to call the API.

Comment: Please update your post with a stackblitz that reproduces the issue.

Comment: well, I cant even get Router working - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzdrng

Comment: I've made ammendments to your stackblitz. You were missing 2 things: a `<router-outlet>` tag on your `app.component.html` and you needed to import the HttpClientModule inside the AppModule (the root of the application, which is where the service looks for the HttpClient service).

Comment: I dont see you mods

Comment: injection error showing on colleges
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-injection-error1

Comment: It looks like the missing piece of the puzzle on the StackBlitz was the missing import for the HttpClientModule on the AppModule. Here is an updated StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-injection-error1-6kl56z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts